# How do you change the HTTP verb for DalekJS tests?

Tags: functional-testing, dalekjs

The DalekJS documentation for the open() action says "You can forge GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and HEAD requests".

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I need to send POST, PUT & DELETE requests to the server for some tests.

Answer (score 0):

per definition the [Webdriver Spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/default/webdriver-spec.html) & the underlying [JSON-Wire protocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) do not support manipulation the HEADERS of a request.

That seems like a limitation, but makes sense if you think about what the protocol is designed for. It is designed to "simulate" a "real" user. What a real user normally doesn't do, is changing the HEADERS of its request.

There are other tools if you want to test a REST interface, Dalek isn't (becauseof the underlying protocol) not designed to test such things.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I agree it's limited, there are times when a real user would be POSTing things. I've solved this by using CasperJS which allows you to change the PhantomJS headers quite easily.

Comment: Yep. Using CasperJS is probably the best way to go, at least if you need to combine it with UI tests. If you do not need to do UI testing of any kind, try [visionmedia/supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest)